# Returning raw entities from Azure Table Storage in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, odata, azure-table-storage

My JavaScript objects/entities look like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: 'foo',
  timestamp: new Date()
}
```

The entities I need to pass to the Azure TableService are going to look something like this:

```
{
  id: { '_': 1, '$': 'Edm.Int32' },
  name: { '_': 'foo', '$': 'Edm.String' },
  timestamp:{ '_': new Date(), '$': 'Edm.DateTime' },
}
```

This is easily done using the `entityGenerator` and this is also the format in which the entities are returned from the TableService.

Is it possible though to return the raw values from the TableService when [fetching data](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableService.html#retrieveEntity) from a table?
I don't really need all of these [OData types and metadata](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/9fdc1562ae4a5103dd0371d4c224bd700cb19d06/lib/services/table/internal/odatahandler.js#L155) on my JavaScript objects.

I might need to use something like a [PropertyResolver](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/TableService.html#propertyResolver) but the documentation is quite confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `entityResolver` to achieve this.

**Example:**

```
var entityResolver = function(entity) {
    var resolvedEntity = {};

    for(key in entity) {
        resolvedEntity[key] = entity[key]._;
    }
    return resolvedEntity;
}

var options = {};
options.entityResolver = entityResolver;

tableSvc.retrieveEntity('mytable', 'hometasks', '1', options, function(error, result, response) {

    if(!error) {
        console.log('result: ', result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Seems a bit hacky but it does the job

Comment: Thanks @AaronChen it does the trick. (Bit hacky, yes, but works!)

Answer (score 5):

How about trying with `options` parameter?

```
tableService.retrieveEntity(tableName, partitionKey, rowKey, {payloadFormat:"application/json;odata=nometadata"}, function(error, result, response) {});
```

It can be used also with queries:

```
tableService.queryEntities(tableName, query, null,{payloadFormat:"application/json;odata=nometadata"}, function(error,result, response) {});
```

And to get cleaner json you might take `response.body` instead `result`.

Example:

```
tableService.retrieveEntity(tableName, partitionKey, rowKey, {payloadFormat:"application/json;odata=nometadata"}, function(error, result, response) {
        if (!error)
        {
            var myEntity = response.body;
        }
});
```

Comment: `application/json;odata=nometadata` doesn't actually return NO metadata... and the `response.body` was a decent option but that treats all of my properties as strings so that's not the best solution either. Worth a shot though, thanks!